# Run a python Code in Android app

Tags: android, python

I am trying to develop an Android App to read an python file, interpret it, and display the result of the code on the screen.I am beginner in android and have fair knowledge of python. How can i go about it? Is there any tool that i can use?

Comment: Did you try by using Google? https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android and https://ep2013.europython.eu/conference/talks/developing-android-apps-completely-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Using Kivy's [python-for-android project](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) would work as a starting point that can compile the python interpreter and bundle it in an android application, but you'd need to create a new frontend (in terms of the new toolchain, a bootstrap) to actually run the python code. You could check the kivy launcher stuff (built into the pygame bootstrap) to see how to call the python interpreter from java code.